# React setState + Where does 'prevState' come from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and JavaScript.
While going through the tutorial, I got to this example code of a component, which creates a toggle button.
This is part of the code:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({    // prevState?
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        }));
    }
```

2 things that are bugging me here:

1. Where did the `prevState` argument come from?
   I don't see anything like `var prevState = this.state;` before calling it, and still, it works.
2. The syntax of the arrow function: why the parentheses after the arrow?
   Why doesn't the usual `arg => { statement; }` syntax work here?

Sorry for the newbie questions...

Comment: A single line arrow function doesn't require {}, but it can be used as such. `prevState` is just a parameter to the callback, it's stored natively in react

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. `prevState` is provided by [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) along with `props`, both of which are optional.

   - **Update 04/13/19**: React has changed the setState function documentation by renaming `prevState` to `updater`. The callback function still takes two arguments; the `state` and `props` at the time the change is being applied.
2. The parenthesis allow multiple lines where if you didn't use the parenthesis you'd be forced to used a `return`. You could use a single line but you don't need the curly braces.

   - **Update**: I forgot to mention a specific case where it is required to have parenthesis. If you're returning an object without a `return` statement you must wrap it in parenthesis. Thank you @joedotnot for catching that. So `() => {foo: true}` will throw an error because it looks like a function and `foo: true` is an invalid line. To fix this it must look like `() => ({ foo: true })`

Comment: Answer 2. does not explain it for my case. If i use this.setState(
     (prevState) => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}) ); all on one line it works. BUT a) without the curly braces, it will error. and b) without the standard brackets no error, but does not increment at all. So for me i require both brackets on RHS of arrow syntax like this  this.setState( (prevState) => ({ key: value}) );

Comment: You're correct, that's a case I missed to explain. When you're returning an object you must wrap it in parenthesis if you don't have the `return` statement. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The link to the React docs you provided doesn't bring up prevState in any of it's actual descriptive text. Maybe it did in previous versions of the documentation?

I looked up descriptions of prevState() elsewhere but none of them actual describe what it does even though it seems crucial when using state in React. It's so odd.

Comment: @DeltaFlyer the only case where I saw prevState is used, was in the componentDidUpdate method (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) . I'm going to assume that it applies for the setState method as well since setState re-renders the component with the updated state change, similar to componentDidUpdate. It basically would work the same, taking the previous state and merging it with the new state changes.Like if you were updating a counter.    this.setState((prevState) => {key : prevState.key + 1})

Comment: @DeltaFlyer I've updated my answer to include the change in the React documentation. It used to be called `prevState`. The crucial thing to understand with this function is that the "state [in the updater function] is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied".

Comment: Also, is "prevState" a magic word or can it be any variable name?

Comment: So if the argument for setState is a function then setState will supply this function with the current state as its parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Im use this. (Example)

```
const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
const [dataAction, setDataAction] = useState({name: '', description: ''});

const _handleChangeName = (data) => {
    if(data.name)
        setDataAction( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   name : data.name }));
    if(data.description)
        setDataAction( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   description : data.description }));
  };
```

Comment: This is one of my working examples used "prevState"