# how is the prevItem getting the value of the previous item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-hook-form

i have made a todo app and i am trying to change the state of the array and for that i used an onclick method.can someone explain how it is actually working and is able to log the value of my last items.

```
function App() {
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

function handleChange(event) {
const newValue = event.target.value;
setInputText(newValue);
}

function addItem() {
setItems(function (prevItems) {
  console.log(prevItems);
  return [...prevItems, inputText];
});
setInputText("");
 }

    return (
    <div className="container">
  <div className="heading">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="form">
    <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" />
    <button onClick={addItem}>
      <span>Add</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      {items.map((todoItem) => (
        <li>{todoItem}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
<    /div>
  );
   }
```

Comment: Is it a problem or you just want to know, how it works?

Comment: no its not a problem i just want to know how it worked

Comment: Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655402/react-setstate-where-does-prevstate-come-from/41655487), you can find more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState + Where does 'prevState' come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655402/react-setstate-where-does-prevstate-come-from)

Answer (score 1):

prevValue is an event property which stores previous string values. So, when you use it as an event it sends back the previously stored value.

Answer (score 0):

React assigns a value to prevItem using the signature of setItems ( a setter param of useState):

- If you call setItems(value) it will set the value to items  - param of setItems is not a function
- If you call setItems(function(prevValue){ return newValue}) the returned newValue will be set to items  - param is a function with the first argument set to prevValue by react